# How can display or stream the output of OpenCV to an HTML page or some other client applications

Tags: c++, html, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming

I want to implement the routine to send or write the OpenCV output frames to HTML or any other applications by using the network protocol such RTMP or RTSP etc.

I have tried and search a lot for this, but I did not find any solution.

The routine is like this:

- Reading the frames from IP camera by using `RTSP` protocol. (**done**)
- Process the frames (face detection... etc). (**done**)
- Now I want to send/show the frames in the browser or any other
  client application. (**problem**)

**What have I done so far:**

- Sending the frames to a server (because the program is running on a
  different machine) then the server using `WebSocket` sends the frames to the webpage. (which is very costly process, CPU, and RAM become very
  slow and stop the processing).
- The second, I have tried to use the `OpenCV` `VideoWriter` class to open
  a stream and write the frames into that, but it was not opening the
  stream.

**Now the question is:**
Can we use OpenCV built-in functions to broadcast or to write the frames to stream? If yes, then how it can be possible to achieve that. If not, so how we can implement this routine in a stable way? Are there any better way or framework to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
command = 'ffmpeg -i - -f flv [streaming_url]'

import subprocess as sp

proc = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE,shell=False)
proc.stdin.write(frame.tostring())
```

Use the ffmpeg to generate the rtmp stream. Pipe in the images to ffmpeg command using stdin.